# Pass click event with offset to contentEditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, contenteditable, jquery-events

I have a div (`.top`) that is on top of another div (`.text`). If `.top` is clicked it should hide and `.text` should get editable. I also give `.text` directly the focus.

Unfortunately the cursor is always at the beginning then. If it would have been clicked directly then the cursor would be were the user has clicked.

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MHgde/).

Is there a way to pass the click event from `.top` to `.text` with the correct offset (as this seems to be needed for setting the correct cursor position)?

Comment: I am missing the point of the top div. If you tell us why, we might be able to offer you a better alternative.

Comment: I have to show an image on top of the editable element. Another thing is that links should not behave like links (e.g. when mouse get over them the cursor should not change).

Answer (score 0):

I have two ideas on this. Firstly avoid the issue by switching classes to change the style of the editable version rather than having two divs, one of which you disable.

The other idea is to attach a click handler in the 'capture phase' rather than the more traditional bubble phase so that the event continues to propagate and the edit box gets the click. I'm not sure right now how to do that in jQuery.

Comment: Nice idea. Unfortunately it doesn't work. The cursor does not show up when focusing the .text element. I used event bubbling, see http://jsfiddle.net/qUE8T/

Answer (score 0):

The click event is being fired by the DIV. It doesn't know WHERE the click occurred. To do that you'd have to keep track of mouse events as well. This is not difficult in itself.

From the mouse x,y you can calculate the DIV x,y and transform the coordinates. This also is not difficult.

The problem arises is that there is no direct correlation between the characters in the DIV and the click. To do this you'd basically need to insert an element into the DIV and iterate its position in your text until you match the approximate mouse click position. It will likely not be an exact match since you're not clicking at the start or end of a character exactly.

Then you have to figure out where this is and move the cursor there in code.